# Can someone explain why is Int (total) different value than Double (total)

Tags: swift, variables, testing, constants

[image]

I don’t understand why Double (total) value is 15600 and Int (total) value is 15599?

```
func race(_ v1: Int, _ v2: Int, _ g: Int) -> [Int]? {
    var vd: Double = Double(v2) - Double(v1)
    var total = Double(3600) * (Double(g) / vd)
    var n = Int(total)
    
    var h = n / 3600
    var m = (n - (3600 * h)) / 60
    var s = (n - (m * 60) - (h * 3600))
    return [h, m, s]
}

race(243, 270, 117)
```

Comment: possibly because you are rounding the double to an integer after the division, while you do it directly on the int when the value are int(s).

Comment: In this particularly case total is already rounded number, but for all other cases is not and function is working correctly .

Answer (score 1):

The `Int.init(Double)` conversion initializer truncates all fractional digits. Quoting the documentation:

> Any fractional part of the value passed as source is removed, rounding the value toward zero.

The computed value of `total` is `15599.999999999998` which is rounded and displayed as `15600` in the side panel. However, truncating the fractional digits results in integer value `15559`.

If you want rounding, use `Int(round(total))`.

Comment: Agreed. The real question is why does the side panel display a float as a rounded value rather than as a double?